# Redraw issue in Highcharts 3D Scatter Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, redraw, scatter3d

Here I'm working on Highcharts 3D Scatter chart, based on the sample [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CJ_Shijo/tfr88reu/2/). In the fiddle,I used to redraw the chart, while emptying the div which contain chart,scatter points get removed ,but the 3D container is not removed.And hence chart is not redrawing.

javascript code :

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'scatter',
            width: 500,
            height: 550,
            marginTop:150,
            margin: 100,
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                drag: {
                        enabled: true,
                    flipAxes: true,
                    snap: 15,
                    animateSnap: true
                                },
                alpha: 15,
                beta: 30,
                depth: 300,
                viewDistance: 5,
                fitToPlot: false,
                frame: {
                    bottom: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)' },
                    back: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.04)' },
                    side: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.06)' }
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Draggable box'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click and drag the plot area to rotate in space'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                width: 10,
                height: 10,
                depth: 10
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            title: null
        },
        xAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            gridLineWidth: 1
        },
        zAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            showFirstLabel: false
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Reading',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [[1, 6, 5], [8, 7, 9], [1, 3, 4], [4, 6, 8], [5, 7, 7], [6, 9, 6], [7, 0, 5], [2, 3, 3], [3, 9, 8], [3, 6, 5], [4, 9, 4], [2, 3, 3], [6, 9, 9], [0, 7, 0], [7, 7, 9], [7, 2, 9], [0, 6, 2], [4, 6, 7], [3, 7, 7], [0, 1, 7], [2, 8, 6], [2, 3, 7], [6, 4, 8], [3, 5, 9], [7, 9, 5], [3, 1, 7], [4, 4, 2], [3, 6, 2], [3, 1, 6], [6, 8, 5], [6, 6, 7], [4, 1, 1], [7, 2, 7], [7, 7, 0], [8, 8, 9], [9, 4, 1], [8, 3, 4], [9, 8, 9], [3, 5, 3], [0, 2, 4], [6, 0, 2], [2, 1, 3], [5, 8, 9], [2, 1, 1], [9, 7, 6], [3, 0, 2], [9, 9, 0], [3, 4, 8], [2, 6, 1], [8, 9, 2], [7, 6, 5], [6, 3, 1], [9, 3, 1], [8, 9, 3], [9, 1, 0], [3, 8, 7], [8, 0, 0], [4, 9, 7], [8, 6, 2], [4, 3, 0], [2, 3, 5], [9, 1, 4], [1, 1, 4], [6, 0, 2], [6, 1, 6], [3, 8, 8], [8, 8, 7], [5, 5, 0], [3, 9, 6], [5, 4, 3], [6, 8, 3], [0, 1, 5], [6, 7, 3], [8, 3, 2], [3, 8, 3], [2, 1, 6], [4, 6, 7], [8, 9, 9], [5, 4, 2], [6, 1, 3], [6, 9, 5], [4, 8, 2], [9, 7, 4], [5, 4, 2], [9, 6, 1], [2, 7, 3], [4, 5, 4], [6, 8, 1], [3, 4, 0], [2, 2, 6], [5, 1, 2], [9, 9, 7], [6, 9, 9], [8, 4, 3], [4, 1, 7], [6, 2, 5], [0, 4, 9], [3, 5, 9], [6, 9, 1], [1, 9, 2]]
        }]
    });
```

Please suggest a method to redraw 3d scatter chart.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the color setting outside your method will fix your problem. See more information about that here: http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/pie-char-uncaught-typeerror-a-indexof-is-not-a-function-t33161/

I also moved chart outside the method so that `destroy()` could be called on it. This will prevent memory leaks.

```js
var chart;

// Give the points a 3D feel by adding a radial gradient
Highcharts.getOptions().colors = $.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
    return {
        radialGradient: {
            cx: 0.4,
            cy: 0.3,
            r: 0.5
        },
        stops: [
            [0, color],
            [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.2).get('rgb')]
        ]
    };
});

function  scatterChart(Data) {
    // Set up the chart
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'scatter',
            width: 500,
            height: 550,
            marginTop:150,
            margin: 100,
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                drag: {
                        enabled: true,
                    flipAxes: true,
                    snap: 15,
                    animateSnap: true
                                },
                alpha: 15,
                beta: 30,
                depth: 300,
                viewDistance: 5,
                fitToPlot: false,
                frame: {
                    bottom: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)' },
                    back: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.04)' },
                    side: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.06)' }
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Draggable box'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click and drag the plot area to rotate in space'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                width: 10,
                height: 10,
                depth: 10
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            title: null
        },
        xAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            gridLineWidth: 1
        },
        zAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            showFirstLabel: false
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series:Data
    });
}

var scatterData = [{
            name: 'Reading',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [[1, 6, 5], [8, 7, 9], [1, 3, 4], [4, 6, 8], [5, 7, 7], [6, 9, 6], [7, 0, 5], [2, 3, 3], [3, 9, 8], [3, 6, 5], [4, 9, 4], [2, 3, 3], [6, 9, 9], [0, 7, 0], [7, 7, 9], [7, 2, 9], [0, 6, 2], [4, 6, 7], [3, 7, 7], [0, 1, 7], [2, 8, 6], [2, 3, 7], [6, 4, 8], [3, 5, 9], [7, 9, 5], [3, 1, 7], [4, 4, 2], [3, 6, 2], [3, 1, 6], [6, 8, 5], [6, 6, 7], [4, 1, 1], [7, 2, 7], [7, 7, 0], [8, 8, 9], [9, 4, 1], [8, 3, 4], [9, 8, 9], [3, 5, 3], [0, 2, 4], [6, 0, 2], [2, 1, 3], [5, 8, 9], [2, 1, 1], [9, 7, 6], [3, 0, 2], [9, 9, 0], [3, 4, 8], [2, 6, 1], [8, 9, 2], [7, 6, 5], [6, 3, 1], [9, 3, 1], [8, 9, 3], [9, 1, 0], [3, 8, 7], [8, 0, 0], [4, 9, 7], [8, 6, 2], [4, 3, 0], [2, 3, 5], [9, 1, 4], [1, 1, 4], [6, 0, 2], [6, 1, 6], [3, 8, 8], [8, 8, 7], [5, 5, 0], [3, 9, 6], [5, 4, 3], [6, 8, 3], [0, 1, 5], [6, 7, 3], [8, 3, 2], [3, 8, 3], [2, 1, 6], [4, 6, 7], [8, 9, 9], [5, 4, 2], [6, 1, 3], [6, 9, 5], [4, 8, 2], [9, 7, 4], [5, 4, 2], [9, 6, 1], [2, 7, 3], [4, 5, 4], [6, 8, 1], [3, 4, 0], [2, 2, 6], [5, 1, 2], [9, 9, 7], [6, 9, 9], [8, 4, 3], [4, 1, 7], [6, 2, 5], [0, 4, 9], [3, 5, 9], [6, 9, 1], [1, 9, 2]]
        }];

scatterChart(scatterData);
chart.destroy();
scatterChart(scatterData);
```